Convert Date and Time to a Date Time
I have a field date__c of type date and a field start_time__c of type time.  I would like to convert this via formula into a datetime field start_date_time__c.  I've found some suggestions online but none of them seem to work.
I've tried: DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(Date__c) & " " & TEXT(start_time__c)) (returns blank/null value) and   DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(Date__c) & " " & (start_time__c )) which throws an error.
Any other suggestions?

tl;dr
You can get close, but this is just one of those things that formulas are not well suited for. Just use a single Datetime field if at all possible.
Longer version
What's the issue with DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(Date__c) & " " & TEXT(start_time__c))?
DATETIMEVALUE() is the right thing to be using, it appears.
It is very specific about the format when you use a string.
"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
The documentation for TEXT() says

Dates are returned in the form of YYYY-MM-DD

So that's not the issue
Documentation offers no guidance for what happens with Times though, but that's easy enough for us to test. Turns out that TEXT(Some_Time_Field__c) returns a value like 03:24:23.757. It includes milliseconds.
That's the issue, you're inadvertently including milliseconds, and that's enough of a deviation for the formula to not work (but not enough of a deviation for it to not be able to save or fail the syntax check).
So, how do we fix it?
As is the common theme with formulas, if you can't do things with just a few function calls, the amount of repetition/complexity/function calls quickly explodes.
Since we can't use TEXT(Start_Time__c), you need to break it out into hours/minutes/seconds yourself.
DATETIMEVALUE(
    TEXT(Date__c) 
    & " "
    & TEXT(HOUR(Start_Time__c)) & ":" & TEXT(MINUTE(Start_Time__c)) & ":" & TEXT(SECOND(Start_Time__c))
)

alternatively, we could remove the final 4 characters of the text-ified time (.757 in my example = 4 characters)
DATETIMEVALUE(
    TEXT(Date__c) 
    & " "
    & LEFT(TEXT(Start_Time__c), LEN(TEXT(Start_Time__c)) - 4)
)

So I put in a Date of 2024-11-26
and a Time of 9:30:00 PM (21:30:00), which is roughly when I'm writing this (UTC-6)
and as a result, I get
... 11-26-2024 3:30 PM
Wait... 11-26-2024 at 3:30 PM and not 9:30 PM?
Yep, one of the other important parts about DATETIMEVALUE() (and TIMEVALUE() for that matter) is that they always give you a result in GMT (UTC+0) and there's nothing we can do to change that behavior.
The resulting Datetime is in GMT (and normal Datetime fields are also stored in GMT), and Salesforce adjusts the time in the UI when the field is displayed.
Depending on the selected time and the timezone of the user viewing the result of the formula field, you'll be some number of hours off. The date itself could end up being displayed as a day earlier or later than the one that was selected.
Formulas don't have a good way to account for the user's timezone
Best case scenario, everyone who would be using this are all in a single timezone. If that's the case, then you can add a static offset to offset Salesforce's offset.
For me in UTC-6 land, that'd look like
DATETIMEVALUE(
    TEXT(Date__c) 
    & " "
    & TEXT(HOUR(Start_Time__c)) & ":" & TEXT(MINUTE(Start_Time__c)) & ":" & TEXT(SECOND(Start_Time__c))
)
/* Accounting for my timezone */
/* <datetime> + 0.25 (or 6.0/24.0) will add 6 hours*/
/* <datetime> - (1.0/12.0) would be the offset for the UTC+2 timezone*/
/* add when your timezone is UTC-<number>, subtract when it's UTC+<number>*/
+ (6.0/24.0)

There's no real good way to adjust for that on a per-user basis. A hierarchical custom setting (which you can set per-user values for) can get close to a per-user offset, but that's going to be hell to set up and maintain.
This would be easier in code
In Apex, we do have a way to tell Salesforce if we're working in the running user's timezone, or if we want to work in GMT
Account myAcc = [SELECT Id, Date__c, Start_Time__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '001000000000000AAA'];
// We actually have a method that can make a Datetime out of a Date and a Time
// Much less fuss
Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstance(myAcc.Date__c, myAcc.Start_Time__c);
system.debug(dt);           // The data is still stored in GMT, so this shows us
                            //   2024-11-27 03:30:00
system.debug(dt.format());  // Formatting to my locale (and timezone) shows us
                            //   11/26/2024, 9:30 PM

But the easiest and most reliable thing would be to just use a Datetime field
The Salesforce UI has a decent date/time picker.
Unless there's a very specific reason that you have to avoid it, you may as well save yourself the trouble.

That's a great explanation, thank you! Question: There is a formula to calculate user's timezone. Could this somehow serve as input for it? (After my office hours I might have a stab at this myself ;-) )

@FelixvanHove My gut feeling is that it'd run over the compiled character limit (and if not, it would end up looking like a disaster). Just copy/pasting that formula as is should work though, but Summer Time / Daylight Saving Time will present an issue. This is also a prime example of a formula "exploding" when you try to do something just a bit outside of what formulas are intended to do.

This is perfect!  Thank you.

In fact the best reference for time zone calculations in Salesforce formulas is here ... - but this is only for Time... - okay, I'm not pursuing this anymore ;-)
